# How to create report having classes and its corresponding tests with extent reports

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have the following testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite" verbose="8">
<parameter name="nodeURL" value=""></parameter>
<listeners>
<listener class-name="com.org.CustomExtentReporter"></listener>
</listeners>
    <test name="Default test1">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.org.SuiteConfiguration">
            </class>
            <class name="com.org.web.HomePage"> </class>
            <class name="com.org.web.Dashboard"> </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

In above xml i have two classes, these will create the report with 4 test node and its log in extent reports.

I want the report to be generated in the following manner:

### Test Class1

- Test case 1
- Test case 2

### Test Class2

- Test case 1
- Test case 2

Now when the user clicks on Test Case 1, the log/result will get displayed corresponding to test class only.

Can we do that using Extent Reporting? I am using ITestListener for testng reporting.

```
public class CustomExtentReporter implements ITestListener {

    ExtentReports extent = ExtentManager.getInstance();
    public static ExtentTest test;

    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        //System.out.println("onTestStart called ...");
        test = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
    }

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        //test = extent.createTest("passTest");
        //System.out.println("onTestSuccess called ...");
        test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "Test Case Status is passed", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) result.getTestContext().getAttribute("driver");
        //System.out.println("onTestFailure called ...");
        //test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
        String screenShotPath = ScreenShotRecorder.captureScreenshot(driver, result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getThrowable() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
        try {
            test.fail(result.getThrowable()).addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            test.log(Status.FAIL, "!!!!!!!!! Exception occurred while attaching the screenshot to extent report");
        }
        //test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getThrowable() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
    }

    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        test.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " - Test Case Skipped", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
    }

    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage called ...");
    }

    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        //System.out.println("onStart called ...");
        //System.out.println("test name ::: "+ context.getName());
        //test = extent.createTest(context.getName());
    }

    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        //System.out.println("onFinish called ...");
        extent.flush();
        extent.removeTest(test);
    }
```

Comment: Both these examples create a hierarchical structure: http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#extent-testng-report-builder or here:  http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#testng-itestlistener

Comment: I am using Extent report v2.41.1. My question is the same as asked by @vermaraj.